# Is there any change require in existing wcf web service if a new client is willing to implement queue at their end?

Tags: .net, wcf

There is one WCF web service which is currently used by a client. The client calls the web service and response is returned in the same call (synchronous) also service is secured with message based security.

A new client is willing to consume the same operation but they wanted to implement the queue at their end.

Please suggest if there will be any change require at web service end ?

Comment: What is "the queue" and what stops the client from implementing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queued WCF bindings only support one way operations. So unless your service operation is one way then you cannot have a client call it via a queued binding.

Having the response of a synchronous service operation queued on client is flat out impossible with WCF. The client would effectively have to become a service and expose one way operations for your "service" to call.

So yes it would require massive and complete change of your existing service.